# iPod-Touch to play Movies from PC on PS3?

Tags: wireless-networking, networking, ipod-touch, ps3, streaming

Is it possible to use my iTouch to communicate with my PC and PS3 to play movies? Almost like a glorified remote-control, working over my wireless network?

Comment: You should change the tag (and title) to iPod touch. Otherwise, users searching for the same thing will not be able to find this question.

Comment: What's an iTouch? I've heard of an iPod touch. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[mbPowertools](http://www.mbpowertools.com) has a collection of nice remote control software.

I've used the [WiFi touchpad](http://mbpowertools.net/index.html) with great success during presentations.  This could serve your purposes well, but their newer [Remote](http://mbpowertools.net/pb/wp_ec7e8f60/wp_ec7e8f60.html) product will probably do what you need.

You can also use the Apple Remote application to control iTunes...

Either way...  its REALLY cool to be able to control your PC from your iPod.

Answer (score 1):

There's also an app for the iPhone called vlcRemFree, which allows you to remote control [vlc](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).  It's quite good - certainly does the job.

Answer (score 1):

[Touchpad Elite](http://www.jaaduvnc.com/touchpad) -- wireless mouse/keyboard control. The great thing about this app is that it uses the VNC protocol, so you don't have to install some proprietary control app on the desktop side (and you don't have to install anything at all on Mac desktops, as VNC support is built in to the OS).

Answer (score 0):

[RemoteApp](http://www.tenjin.org/RemotePad/) is a free open-source app you can find in the App Store for controlling a PC (you run a little Windows app that it communicates with over your wireless network) that work very well. Don't know about PS3 though...